# Prevent Chrome from auto opening Sign-in tab

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Using Windows 7 Home Premium running Version 45.0.2454.101 m of Chrome.

First off, this has *nothing* to do with startup options and *nothing* to do with homepage.

When chrome has been open for several hours with one or more tabs open, at some point a new tab is sent to me, telling me to sign into Chrome.  I do not want  Chrome to canvass me and take me off of the tab that has been running.

Short of choosing another browser, how do I prevent chrome from affecting my browser in this way.

I have new tab redirect, Google analytics opt-out, ghostery, adblock, adblock plus installed as extensions, among others.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a screenshot of your issue.

Answer (score 0):

First off,  as of the date of your question (today, 12-20-15) chrome 45 anything is old and has little support.

Secondly,

1) Did you ever login to chrome |google in the time leading up to this ?

2) Are you using a site that is asking to 'login with google' or with something tied to your google bits?

3) Using guest mode (incognito --aka "pron mode") has zero requirement for signing in this would be the fastest way to prevent signin issues HOWEVER you would have to  either  forgo your extensions or  login again to re-enable them in incognito mode...

Comment: "Support" from google may increase my safety but I suspect that it has nothing to do with diminishing the hold that google wants to have on my browsing habits.  I am one of those people who likes status quo and mistrust updates unless there is a demonstrated safety issue fix that outweighs any decrease in privacy or function. Regarding #1, I believe I signed in once in the past but abandoned it. #2 using no such site.  #3: Are you saying that I can sign in with incognito as default and keep extensions active?  Please help me with this.

Comment: as per #3  start  incognito then sign in to sync up your extensions and  go (you will need to do even NEW session tho)